# Status Page - Anyone can edit

Tags: php

Was wondering if anyone knew of a good "status page" that I could use or point me in the correct direction, without having to rewrite a bunch of code for our organization?

Basically, it would be a page with a text area to post and update.

Anyone in the organization should be able to post, as this is an internal only tool.

We just want to have a centralized place to get a status of updates.  I know I could do this with my own code, but I don't exactly have a bunch of free time and wanted to know if there was a way to do this with tools already out there.

I've already tried wordpress, but that requires you to have a user login to have permissions to post.  I literally want it to be public, almost like a wiki, only more along the lines of twitter (`update->post->everyone sees` - without any form of authentication)

Answer (score 3):

It really sounds like you should just run a simple wiki for this.  If the website is internal-only then you don't really have to worry about spam.  Set up something like [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/) and leave it wide open for anyone to update.  You should probably also set up [email notifications](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/Notify) just to make sure nobody accidentally erases a page or posts bogus data.

PmWiki is a good choice because it's dead simple to set up and stores all data in text files so you don't even need to configure a database to use it.

I understand that doesn't give you exactly what you want, in that it requires free-form editing of the wiki page.  As an alternative to that you could set up a [PmWiki form](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/Forms) so users could just type in the update and choose 'post' to make it appear on the page in list format.

Answer (score 2):

There are also open source status page dashboards like http://www.stashboard.org/ that you can utilize.

Comment: Looks like a good tool, although I don't know if it meets the OP's criteria of not needing a password to edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about [yourworldoftext](http://www.yourworldoftext.com/)?  I think you can restrict it to members only.

Comment: I do not want it member based.  I want it completely open.

Comment: Well you can have it be open to everyone, but since it's on the net, that means I could see your wall.

Answer (score -2):

There are services dedicated to hosting system status pages such as [Status.io](https://status.io).

(Disclosure: I am the founder of Status.io)